# How to get all received notifications on ios

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it any way to known when an iOS app is launched, if Push notifications were sent to the device ? ( I want to access to the payload to retrieve information from the notification )

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like this to your code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary
*)launchOptions {

    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    //Accept push notification when app is not open
    if (remoteNotif) {      
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
        return YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Note that you will only get the push notification payload if the app was launched by tapping the notification. If it was launched by tapping the app icon, you won't get the payload.

Comment: to be picky, the suggested handler method should probably have the signature -handleRemoteNotification:remoteNotif application:application

Answer (score 1):

There are methods from [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) from where you see if there is notification received

You could see in your AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method if user has launced the app with the notifications e.g

```
UILocalNotification *notif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        irLog(@"Recieved Notification");
    }
```

for local notification you have posted you can have a look at this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
```

for remote notifications you can have a look at this method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```